# inline is not defined in material ui while giving css property

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I am trying to change the css for material -ui
- when I give width its working fine, but when I give display inline I am getting an error ---> inline is not defined
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below

https://codesandbox.io/s/mzj2zp6y0p

```
<Tabs
            value={value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            scrollable
            scrollButtons="on"
            indicatorColor="primary"
            textColor="primary"
            style={{ width: 500 }}
          >
            <Tab
              style={{ display: inline }}
              label="Item One"
              icon={<PhoneIcon />}
            />
            <Tab label="Item Two" icon={<FavoriteIcon />} />

          </Tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

React thinks that inline is a variable you are trying to reference. You need to put it in quotes and then it should work fine. 
style={{ display: "inline" }}

Comment: thanks for your reply...its working...but instead of giving as inline styles, is it possible to put it in separate file and target using class names...is that possible https://codesandbox.io/s/40mmrl9059

Comment: Not familiar with wether or not material ui 'Tab' is able to take a className or not. What I do know is that a lot of react libraries use the style object instead of classname so that they can convert to reactNative easily (className isn't a thing in react native). So you could have a separate file that exports a bunch of different styles that are in JSON. Then you can pass in StylesObject.tab or whatever you call it

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it in quotation marks like so, since it is not actually CSS that you're writing, it's actually JSS:

```
<Tabs
  value={value}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  scrollable
  scrollButtons="on"
  indicatorColor="primary"
  textColor="primary"
  style={{ width: 500 }}
>
    <Tab
        style={{ display: 'inline' }}
        label="Item One"
        icon={<PhoneIcon />}
    />
    <Tab label="Item Two" icon={<FavoriteIcon />} />

</Tabs>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply...its working...but instead of giving as inline styles, is it possible to put it in separate file and target using class names...is that possible https://codesandbox.io/s/40mmrl9059

Comment: Yes, totally. There are many ways you can do this. You can have a directory that stores your components, and another directory for your stylesheets. Then in your main index.js where you call `ReactDOM.render()`, you can import your stylesheets.

Comment: Another common practice is to group each component into its OWN directory, coupled with its own stylesheet and an `index.js` file for exporting easily. I went ahead and added a directory titled `TestComponent` to the codesandbox that you linked here to demonstrate this method.

Comment: thanks for your reply...I saw the sandbox link but I am not able to see the directory...can you paste the link here...Thanks

Comment: oops, my apologies, I figured it'd just update your sandbox.
https://codesandbox.io/s/z6nl1o0nq3

Comment: did my answer end up helping you out?